# Fetch prelogin banner from SSH server using Paramiko without authenticating

Tags: python, ssh, python-3.6, paramiko, banner

I am trying to fetch banner from sever using below code. But the result always says "None", even thought banner exists. I have tried with Python 2 and 3, Paramiko 2.4 and 2.7.0, same result as "None".
Can anyone correct/help me?

The code is based on:
[Is there a way using paramiko and python to get the banner of the ssh server you connected to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530155/is-there-a-way-using-paramiko-and-python-to-get-the-banner-of-the-ssh-server-you)

The banner is configured in `sshd_config` using `Banner` directive.

```
# !/usr/bin/python

import paramiko

def grab_banner(ip_address, port):
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    try:
        client.connect(ip_address, port=port, username='username',
                       password='bad-password-on-purpose')
    except:
        return client._transport.get_banner()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print grab_banner('192.168.1.26', 22)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In general I believe that your code should work. But as after failed password authentication, Paramiko tries in vain various other authentication methods, the further attempts will discard the banner (it looks like a bug in Paramiko to me).

Prevent that by setting `look_for_keys` and `allow_agent` in [`SSHClient.connect`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect):

```
try:
  client.connect(ip_address, port=port, username='username',
                 password='bad-password-on-purpose',
                 look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
except:
  return client._transport.get_banner()
```

---

Here is a fix for Paramiko that allows retrieving the banner without the above workaround:
https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/pull/438

Comment: Thank you for this answer! It worked perfectly. I had my "banner grabber" script working initially but it just... stopped... one day. Your solution worked correctly. Hopefully they merge that pull request!