# How can I extract the mac address from the pre-authentication banner message in SSH using Python?

Tags: python, ssh

PuTTY window:
[image]

How to read MAC from the Pre-authentication banner message from SSH server?
After connected to device with the PuTTY and user and is entered, Banner message is displayed. And I want to read the MAC address from the banner display. Please help

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Python Paramiko library](https://www.paramiko.org/), the banner is available via [`Transport.get_banner`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/transport.html#paramiko.transport.Transport.get_banner).

For an example, see
[Is there a way using Paramiko and Python to get the banner of the SSH server you connected to?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19530155/850848)